# segmentation fault while reading a FITS file with healpix

Tags: c, linux, fits

I'm trying to open a FITS file with healpix using a C code:

```cpp
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "chealpix.h"
#include "fitsio.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "fitsio2.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

        char *coordsys="G";
        char *order="RING";
        long nside;
        long *p_nside=&nside;
        nside=512.;
        float *map;
        map=read_healpix_map("file.fits",p_nside,coordsys,order);
         
    return(0);
}
```

This code returns a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` when using `gdb`, I get

```cpp
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
ffgkys (status=0x7fffffffdaf4, comm=<optimized out>, value=0x55555555a004 "G", keyname=<optimized out>, 
    fptr=<optimized out>) at getkey.c:808
808     value[0] = '\0';
```

This is the first time I am using healpix and I have no idea what is causing the problem. Has anyone any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation of [`read_healpix_map()`](https://healpix.sourceforge.io/doc/html/csub_read_healpix_map.htm):

[image]

`ordering` and `coordsys` are *output* arguments - they are pointers to space into which the function will write results.  You have passed pointers to string constants in memory that will normally be marked read-only and may not be sufficiently large to receive the result in any case.

`nside` is also an output argument, initialising it to 512 serves no purpose.  You do not need `p_nside`; you can simply pass `&nside`

It is not the most clear of interfaces; specifically it is not clear whether `coordsys` is a string or a single `char`.  The documentation uses single quotes so you might assume `char` but then it does that for `ordering` too and that is clearly a string.  It is  safest to assume `coordsys` is a string - it will do no harm.

```
    char  coordsys[] = "G";    // This will be overwritten
    char  order[] = "NESTED" ; // This will be overwritten, 
                                  initialise to largest expected string
                                  to ensure sufficient space is allocated
    long nside = 0 ;
    float* map = read_healpix_map( "file.fits", &nside, coordsys, order ) ;

    printf( "nside:%ld, coordsys:%s, order:%s", nside, coordsys, order ) ;
```

---

Post Script:  Looking at the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/healpix/code/HEAD/tree/branches/branch_v370r1154/src/C/subs/chealpix.c#l941) both `coordsys` and `ordering` are passed to `fits_read_key()`, so `coordsys` is treated as a string.

Comment: I tried your code, but got the warning "WARNING: Could not find COORDSYS keyword in in file file.fits". How does that work for you?

Comment: @pulsar_hh  I have no idea, TBH I don't even know what HEALPix or a FITS file is - I was just reading and interpreting the documentation from a C code point of view.  It sounds like it is related to the content of file.fits rather then the code.

Comment: @pulsar_hh I guess it will default - what does `coordsys` contain after the call?  If it is "G", change the initialisation to say `"-"` to see if it defaults or just leaves it untouched.

Comment: @pulsar_hh Test with one of the samples from https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_samples.html  perhaps?  The header part is ASCII - I looked at a couple neither contained `COORDSYS`.  Where/how was the warning displayed?  Was it side effect output from the call, or was it dangerously written to `coordsys`?  If the latter, you'll need to make that buffer much bigger, and the documentation sucks.

Comment: I think it was not printing anything, but right now I am facing a `*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted (core dumped)` when running the programm, and I do not know where that come from, because when I tried first it was working.

Comment: I am geeting 
`WARNING: Could not find COORDSYS keyword in in file Pulsar_limits_fix2.fits
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)`
when running the code

Comment: It is output to `stderr`: https://sourceforge.net/p/healpix/code/HEAD/tree/branches/branch_v370r1154/src/C/subs/chealpix.c#l972.  According to https://healpix.sourceforge.io/html/idl_read_fits_map.htm COORDSYS is optional.  Are you expecting it?

Comment: The stack-smashing may be something different or the function is writing more to the buffer than the documentation suggests - it is a terribly unsafe interface for C code.  Use a debugger to determine what is happening.  Of make the buffers arbitrarily large; e.g. `char  order[1024] = "" ;`

Comment: Its just an annoying warning then - not a C code issue.  Deal with the stack error - that is serious.

Comment: The debugger gives me `_GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
`

Comment: I think the code just writes the key  value it finds in the file, it is not restricted to "NESTED" or "RING" as the documentation suggests.  That said none of the files I have inspected have `"ORDERING`" either.

Comment: maybe just increasing the size of the array would work then?

Comment: Yes you need to use the `backtrace` (GDB) command or whatever call stack inspection your debugger provides to see what causes the abort.

Comment: `#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff76f5859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff77603ee in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff788a07c "*** %s ***: terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#3  0x00007ffff7802b4a in __GI___fortify_fail (msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff788a064 "stack smashing detected") at fortify_fail.c:26
#4  0x00007ffff7802b16 in __stack_chk_fail () at stack_chk_fail.c:24
#5  0x00005555555556af in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdd18) at young_pulsar_pop.c:60
`

Comment: Actually, increasing the size of the char array like you suggested works

Comment: Perhaps use a different library - HEALPix is not listed at https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_libraries.html

Comment: It failed at `young_pulsar_pop.c` line 60 - you have not provided that in this quesrtion  (it does not have that many lines). - post a new question.

Comment: Line 60 is the `}` of my main function. Ok I will post a new question-thanks

Comment: That is where it detected the stack error (on return) - something wrong before that, but given your original misunderstanding of the "dangerous"  interface and its poor documentation, that is perhaps not surprising.