# *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted (core dumped) using HEALPix C subroutines

Tags: python, c, stack, coredump, healpy

I am trying to translate a python code into a C code. So I was trying to translate that line:

```py
import healpy as hp  
OldTobySensitivMap = hp.read_map('file.fits', dtype=numpy.float64)
```

This opens a FITS file using the HEALPix projection. So in C I am using the HEALPix library:

```cpp
#include "chealpix.h"
#include "fitsio.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

        char coordsys[]="G";
        char order[]="NESTED";
        long nside=0;
        float *map;
        map=read_healpix_map("file.fits",&nside,coordsys,order);
        printf("nside:%ld, coordsys:%s, order:%s",nside,coordsys,order);     

return(0);

}
```

However, this code returns an error :

```cpp
WARNING: Could not find COORDSYS keyword in in file file.fits
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
```

GDB debugger output is:

```sh
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff76f5859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff77603ee in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff788a07c "*** %s ***: terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#3  0x00007ffff7802b4a in __GI___fortify_fail (msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff788a064 "stack smashing detected") at fortify_fail.c:26
#4  0x00007ffff7802b16 in __stack_chk_fail () at stack_chk_fail.c:24
#5  0x00005555555556af in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdd18) at young_pulsar_pop.c:60
```

Increasing the size of the strings such that:

```sh
        char coordsys[2024]="G";
        char order[2024]="NESTED";
```

Works, but then the output is `nside:512, coordsys:, order:RING`, so I do not really understand what is causing the stack error.

Like it was said by an other user, that HEALPix interface seem to be quite unsafe for C, and the documentation is really poor. I am therefore wondering if I should not simply embed the python code in my C programm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [related documentation](https://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/html/csubnode10.htm) :

> read_healpix_map
>
> This routine reads a full sky HEALPix map from a FITS file
>
> Location in HEALPix directory tree: src/C/subs/read_healpix_map.c
>
> FORMAT float *read_healpix_map(char *infile, long *nside, char *coordsys, char *ordering)
>
> ARGUMENTS

```
 | name&dimensionality  | kind | in/out | description     |

   read_healpix_map       float   OUT     array containing the map read from the file 

   infile                 char    IN      FITS file containing a full sky to be read

   nside                   long   OUT     HEALPix resolution parameter of the map

   coordsys                char   OUT     astronomical coordinate system of 
 pixelisation (either 'C', 'E' or 'G' standing respectively for Celestial=equatorial, Ecliptic or Galactic) 

   ordering                char   OUT     HEALPix pixel ordering (either 'RING' or 'NESTED')
```

What we see is that `coordsys` and `ordering` are **output** parameters for this function. That means this function expect char buffers with a defined size to store the related output string. As described in this documentation, the provided buffer for `coordsys` should be, for **ASCII string**  a `char [2]` type (storing the coordinate system in one char plus the NULL byte) and `ordering` should be a `char [7]` type (the longest string is *'NESTED'*, 6 char plus the NULL byte).

With `char coordsys[]="G";` and `char order[]="NESTED";`, you're defining the string in the data section of your program. As you use the longest string for order, you should then have sufficient space for the both strings.

### But.

The `read_healpix_map` documentation isn't accurate. The function will store a `TSTRING` object in its `coordsys` and `ordering` parameters, as [its source](https://sourceforge.net/p/healpix/code/HEAD/tree/branches/branch_v370r1154/src/C/subs/chealpix.c#l941) calls the `fits_read_key` function which [store a TSRING object](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/fitsio/c/c_user/node38.html) in theses parameters.

So that's the reason why using 'big size' buffers works.

The best you can do to avoid any troubles is to directly initialize your buffers `coordsys` and `order`  with a `TSTRING` object for "G" and "NESTED". In the `fitsio.h` header [documentation](https://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/%7Emathar/progs/cfitsio_api/fitsio_8h.html), the max length for a keyword is defined with `FLEN_VALUE`. So i suggest you to use:

```c
char coordsys[FLEN_VALUE]="G";
char order[FLEN_VALUE]="NESTED";
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot @Zilog80! How am I supposed to use a tstring in C? I never heard of that type before.

Comment: Just edit to suggest you to use the pre defined `FLEN_VALUE` as buffer size.

Comment: Good spot.  The initialisation was as suggested by me in an earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67841262/segmentation-fault-while-reading-a-fits-file-with-healpix.  Where I was working from the documentation having never come across this library.  I did note there that the documentation was poor, and suggested in comments making the buffers arbitrarily large to see what was being placed in them.

Comment: @Clifford The documentation could be better, yes. However their code should not use output parameter buffers for string manipulations. Do you think we should notify them to update their documentation, if not the library ?